# Raspberry Pi server w/out port forwarding

Tags: networking, ssh, ftp, raspberry-pi, vnc

I would like to remote into my Pi from outside my home network.  The problem is that my apartment provides me with wireless internet and I can't access the router to enable port-forwarding.  Is there any way around this?  A dynamic dns service perhaps?

I would like to use VNC SSH and/or FTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use Team Viewer to remote a station behind NAT without activating port forwarding like in your situation.
You need to create an account on you team viewer application, and register your target station's team viewer to your account.
When you are away, please make sure to always open your target station's team viewer and you will be able remote your target station by first login to your team viewer account. Once you are logged in you will have a list of target station that you have registered. Simply double click one of the list and you can remote your target station.

VNC or SSH will not be able to work behind NAT without activating port forwarding because the router will try to open it's own port instead of your target station.

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping to install Teamviwer in the Raspberry pi as well, and I sent an email off to the temviewer team. This was my response:

Hi Drano

Thank you very much for your message.

Teamviewer does not support ARM architecture. I will forward your suggestion to our product management. Such ideas are always welcome, although I can not promise when or if this Feature will be implemented, as the decision is based on public demand. Nevertheless, your feedback is very important to us as we want to continue to develop TeamViewer based on our user's needs and demands. We will be happy to inform you about realization of this feature.

If you have any further questions on our product, please feel free to contact us.

Best regards,

Harun Rashid
-Support Technician-

P.S.: TeamViewer 9 is ready!